# How to hide all the IFrames in an HTML page if the IFrame source has an XML error?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm facing an issue while I'm trying to show a PDF preview inside an `iframe` tag. I have a page that contains some `iframe`s to display PDF files in the page, the problem is that sometimes the PDF does not exist in the source URL so the `iframe` shows an XML error saying `BlobNotFound`. I want to hide the `iframe` if that error is returned inside the `iframe`'s source.

I have tried this javascript script below:

```
<script>
  const myIframe = document.getElementById('myFrame1');
  fetch('example.xml')
      .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('XML file not found');
          }
          return response.text();
      })
      .then(xmlString => {
          const parser = new DOMParser();
          const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
          // check for errors in the XML content
          const error = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
          if (error.length > 0) {
              myIframe.style.display = 'none'; // hide the iframe if there is an error
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          myIframe.style.display = 'none'; // hide the iframe if there is an error
      });
</script>
```

This code works but only if you specify the `iframe` tag by its ID and I want to rewrite this code to check all the `iframe`s at once.

I have also tried this code below:

```
<script>
  const iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
      const iframe = iframes[i];
      fetch(iframe.src)
          .then(response => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error('XML file not found');
              }
              return response.text();
          })
          .then(xmlString => {
              const parser = new DOMParser();
              const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
              // check for errors in the XML content
              const error = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
              if (error.length > 0) {
                  iframe.style.display = 'none'; // hide the iframe if there is an error
              }
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
              iframe.style.display = 'none'; // hide the iframe if there is an error
          });
  }
</script>
```

This code is supposed to work but somehow it hides all the `iframe`s even if it does not have an error.

P.S.\ This is the XML error of any `iframe` that can't show the PDF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
    <Message>
        The specified blob does not exist.
            RequestId:xxxxxxxx
            Time:timestamp
    </Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hide Iframes with XML Error</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="path/to/pdf1.pdf"></iframe>
  <iframe src="path/to/pdf2.pdf"></iframe>
  <iframe src="path/to/nonexistent.pdf"></iframe>
  <iframe src="path/to/pdf3.pdf"></iframe>
  <script>
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
      var iframe = iframes[i];
      iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        if (event.message === 'BlobNotFound') {
          // Hide all iframes if any one of them has an XML error
          for (var j = 0; j < iframes.length; j++) {
            iframes[j].style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it works on not.

Comment: Thanks, but this script does not seem to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).